# Does a Craft Editor's Guide exist?

Tags: editor

I'm just coming over to Craft from Other CMSes Which Shall Not Be Named. Something I typically do for clients is create custom videos showing how to use the CMS. Now that I'm diving into Craft I'm thinking about creating a general Editor's Guide to show all the nice features of this lovely CMS. (realizing that Craft will be customized to each site's needs)

I've looked around and haven't yet found any similar attempt at showing Craft from an editor's perspective. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for professional-grade videos showing off what Craft can do, then [Jamie has already pointed you in the right direction...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7118/45)

If you'd like to add your own content to help your clients find their way through the construction of your particular project, check out the awesome [Craft Help plugin](https://github.com/70kft/craft-help), which allows you to document the details of how moderate that unique site.

Comment: Thanks @LindseyD  Didn't know about the Help plugin, which looks fantastic. I may create some generic help pages that I can drop in to Help and alter when appropriate. On the other hand, I like the idea of a central resource that can be updated for everyone at one time. Hmmm... decisions, decisions.

Comment: @Kirk: Unless you setup the same simple brochure-style websites for your clients that all use the same fields, as you mentioned, every site is going to be unique (at least it should be). In my experience, the most friction that clients run into is the unique features that you build into the site—for example how this section relates to another, where the home page is pulling content, etc. You might consider recording your training session with the client and then do some quick editing after you're done.

Comment: I built another plugin based similarly off of 70kft's plugin, but instead of writing documentation in flat files you can write it as part of a section in your own Craft install. https://github.com/hillholliday/Craft-User-Manual

Answer (score 2):

The Features section on the Craft site already has some useful videos that may be of interest:

https://buildwithcraft.com/features/matrix

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I've seen all of those and they're more "Craft is great for users and devs" than "how to edit your content with Craft".

Comment: @KirkRoberts No problem, thought I'd share them anyway. As far as I know there isn't one big site or sites that offer Craft tutorials for editors to the extent you are looking to create. Straight Up Craft is a great place for Craft help, but it is more focused on the web professional behind the site, not the clients themselves: http://straightupcraft.com. It looks like you might have found a niche here!